# Visual Studio 2019 ( not VS Code ) shows incomplete python Documentation

Tags: python, visual-studio, documentation

I am using Visual Studio 2019 to code in python (not VS CODE). I have noticed that VS does not show the complete (or at least more than 30 lines ) than what PyCharm is actually doing. I would like to actually learn more about the function while coding.

Does any one have an idea?

[image: Visual Studio]

Pycharm

[image]

Comment: install Pylance and see if it makes a difference (from the extension marketplace)

Comment: @thethiny, I think pylance is only for visual studio CODE right?... do you know any equivalent for Visual Studio 2017/9? ( the full IDE )

Comment: If it's not necessary to use Visual Studio, just use Visual Code as it is better for interpreted languages than Visual Studio, which is better for compiled languages.

Comment: @thethiny.. yeap I get your poitn.. it looks like Microsoft killed his own baby by bringing VS Code in the market.. I am seriously thinking on changing to pyCharm or VS Code.

( meanwhile i kind of found a workaround... see EDIT )

Comment: That's nice, but again, why are you using Visual Studio for an interpreted language? I really want to see your motive behind it as you might have something I'm missing. You can add your edit as an answer and accept it.

Comment: @thethiny. It is basically because I have learned to code first with VBA. and the IDE is basically the same. I am able to find the tools I need without to learn a new Editor  [Watches, Breakdown, Locals. etc].  ( and no one has forced me to change the editor. Not a really "must" thing) .

Comment: You're right. However debugging Python is way easier in Visual Code (at least for me). As long as it's working fine for you, then go ahead! BTW I think the missing definition is simply because you need to scroll down. Try to change font size see if that fixes it.

Comment: @thethiny changing the fontsize/scrolling down did not bring any improvement. I think at the end is something related to the IDE settings ( not willing to invest more time if at the end I will have to change the IDE at some point ).   I have heard good things of VS and PyCharm. maybe at some point I will have to change. Tx for the help/suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a workaround not that user friendly, but it allows me to see the definition in the source code..

[image]
[image]